# Visualization more than two grouping variables with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot similar to this plot from an article:

Plot 1

[image]

I created something similar for my data using R but not precisely the same.

Plot 2

[image]

I heard that I could create plot 1 using matplotlib in Python. Could someone help me with this?

Here is my data in R:

```
data = {
  'year': (1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,
           1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,
           2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,
           2018,2019,2020,2021,2022),
  'LS4': (0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0),
  'LS5': (35,45,37,29,23,32,46,35,47,40,
          52,55,46,38,0,6,47,41,45,43,
          42,49,29,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0),
  'LS7': (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,3,20,24,43,33,42,27,25,26,
          26,38,23,23,28,34,50,56,49,52,
          51,57,54,48,49),
  'LS8': (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,33,60,61,58,53,
          58,60,55,53,49),
  'LS9': (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,6,52),
  'obs': (35,50,37,29,23,32,46,35,47,40,
          52,58,66,62,43,39,89,68,70,69,
          68,87,52,48,28,67,110,117,107,105,
          109,117,109,107,150)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much do whatever you want:

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('year')

start_end = (df.where(df.ne(0)).filter(like='LS')
               .rename_axis(columns='col').stack()
               .reset_index()
               .groupby('col')['year'].agg(['min', 'max'])
            )


#ax = df['obs'].plot.bar()
ax = df.filter(like='LS').plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax.axhline(0, c='k')

unit = (ax.get_ylim()[1]-0)/30

ax.set_ylim(bottom=-df.shape[1]*unit)

for i, t in enumerate(start_end.itertuples(), start=1):
    y = -i*unit
    ref = df.index.min()
    start = t.min-ref
    end = t.max-ref
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((start-0.5, y), end-start+1, unit*0.9, facecolor='#C1C1C1'))
    ax.text((start+end)/2, y+unit//2, t.Index, ha='center', va='center')
```

Output:

[image]

With custom colors:

```
# use here your colormap if custom
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

for i, t in enumerate(start_end.itertuples(), start=1):
    y = -i*unit
    ref = df.index.min()
    start = t.min-ref
    end = t.max-ref
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((start-0.5, y), end-start+1, unit*0.9, facecolor=colors[i-1]))
    ax.text((start+end)/2, y+unit//2, t.Index, ha='center', va='center')
```

Output:

[image]

##### splitting the sub-periods (e.g. LS5)

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('year')

tmp = df[df.ne(0)].filter(like='LS').melt(ignore_index=False).dropna(subset=['value']).reset_index()
g = tmp.groupby('variable')['year'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
start_end = tmp.groupby(['variable', g])['year'].agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index()

#ax = df['obs'].plot.bar()
ax = df.filter(like='LS').plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax.axhline(0, c='k')

unit = (ax.get_ylim()[1]-0)/30

ax.set_ylim(bottom=-df.shape[1]*unit)

# use here your colormap if custom
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

ref = df.index.min()
for i, (k, g) in enumerate(start_end.groupby('variable'), start=1):
    for t in g.itertuples():
        y = -i*unit
        start = t.min-ref
        end = t.max-ref
        ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((start-0.5, y), end-start+1, unit*0.9, facecolor=colors[i-1]))
        ax.text((start+end)/2, y+unit//2, k, ha='center', va='center')
```

Output:

[image]